# How to set task scheduler Start in(Optional) property using Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have created a batch file using the  cmd:

```
SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "Task" /TR "%~dp0\Data.bat" /ST 09:00
```

How to set "Start In" property using cmd ?

Comment: There is no command line option for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SchTasks does not have an option to specify the "Start In" path.

But you can modify your "Data.bat" and insert a CD or PUSHD command at the top to establish the correct working folder.

If you cannot modify "Data.bat", then create a new batch file "callData.bat" with the correct commands:

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\your\Start\Path"
"d:\your\script\path\Data.bat"
```

and then schedule "callData.bat" instead of "Data.bat"

Another option is to schedule cmd.exe and have that set the current folder and execute the batch script. *(note: the quote rules can be a bit tricky - I'm not sure if I got them correct in this case)*

```
SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "Task" /TR "cmd.exe /c cd /d \"c:\your\start\path\" & \"%~dp0\Data.bat\"" /ST 09:00
```

Comment: Thanks dbenham, I tried the first method and it worked.

Comment: If the latter option, which uses cmd.exe, is used, will that prevent Task Scheduler from being able to end the task, because cmd would launch the desired app as a different task?

Comment: @dbenham: I tried inserting the CD command above the SCHTASKS command but it did NOT set the Start In field.  I also tried inserting extra lines so the .bat executes itself after CD'ing to the Start In folder, and that too failed to set the Start In field.  I guess I misunderstood what you meant by Data.bat... you meant the app that the new task will run, if it's a .bat file, and you didn't mean the .bat that creates the Task Scheduler task.

Comment: @DoloresStevens - Q1: I'm pretty sure the launched process is responsible for closing itself - the scheduler does not close it. And the callData.bat does not launch another cmd.exe - it simply transfers control to the desired Data.bat in the same cmd.exe process. Q2: Yes, you misunderstood. The callData.bat is a workaround for the fact that the Start field cannot be set. It simply sets the current directory to the correct location so that it does not matter what the Start In value was. It then transfers control to the desired script.

Comment: @dbenham: (1) Task Scheduler CAN be used to end a task, such as when a .bat executes the SCHTASKS /END command.  My question is whether SCHTASKS /END will fail if the task action uses CMD /C. (2) If you mean the task action launches callData.bat, and callData.bat executes app after cd'ing to working folder, then I have the same question about SCHTASKS /END.  Does it depend on whether the app is a .bat (like OP's Data.bat) or will it succeed no matter the app type? In particular, could SCHTASKS end a Windows GUI app if the Windows Scheduler task used CMD /C or callData.bat?

Comment: @DoloresStevens - Your issue is unrelated to this Q&A - you should probably find a more relevant question, and/or ask your own SO question. It's not really appropriate to be associated with this Q&A.

Comment: @dbenham: I don't view my question as being "my issue" since I'm not suffering from a problem.  I view it as an attempt to clarify whether the solutions proposed for the OP's problem are narrow solutions (work without issues only for tasks that launch bat files) or general solutions (work without issues also for tasks that launch other kinds of apps).  Isn't it best practice when offering a solution to also mention its scope / known limitations?

Comment: @DoloresStevens - The question was explicitly tagged as batch-file. The answer may not be appropriate if dealing with something other than a batch script (or possibly a console application). You have identified one issue that could be a problem with this answer if not dealing with a batch script. But it is not really relevant to the original question.